# Honeycomb images using CSS not visible in SAFARI BROWSER

Tags: image, safari, transform

Creating Honeycomb image using css( transform rotate ) on a webpage which is not working and visible in SAFARI browser only.
Here's the code:

```
.hex {
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Webkit */
      filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
      filter: grayscale(100%);

    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  }

.hex * {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
}

.hexIn {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
     transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);    
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;  
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```